# Sorting Column of dates in R

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a dataframe with a date column. These dates represent the date that a  particular poll result was actually taken. However, the website takes these results and adds them to a table not necessarily on the date of the poll taking. So for example:

- 20/01/2018
- 21/01/2018
- 20/01/2018
- 19/01/2018

so the date at the top (20/01/2018) came in **after** the ones below. But the poll below says 21st and thats the date that the poll was taken so the earliest date that the one above could have been added is the 21st thus the list becomes;

- 21/01/2018
- 21/01/2018
- 20/01/2018
- 19/01/2018

and now my column is sorted. I need to do this for like 50 variables! Suggestions?
I want to sort my dates column such that if i go from bottom to top of the column if a date has a later date below it, then that date becomes that later date too. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze9tF.png)

Comment: Can you run `str(the_name_of_your_data_frame)` and paste the output into the answer? (I can make it a code block if your editor can't perform the 4-space indent)

Comment: 'data.frame': 574 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Poll      : chr  "NBC News/Wall St. JrnlNBC/WSJ" "CNNCNN" "Rasmussen ReportsRasmussen" "GallupGallup" ...
 $ Approve   : num  46 41 50 40 44 40 44 41 44 45 ...
 $ Disapprove: num  52 57 49 54 52 53 52 53 56 54 ...
 $ Spread    : chr  "-6" "-16" "+1" "-14" ...
 $ Date      : POSIXct, format: "2018-11-03" "2018-11-03" ...
>

Comment: Far better to run `dput(the_name_of_your_data)`. Easier to reproduce that way

Comment: @ConorNeilson I suggested that in the deleted version of this question.

Comment: So, `Date` is an actual POSIXct date. `name_of_your_df <- name_of_your_df[order(name_of_your_df$Date),]`

Comment: that's not exactly giving me my desired output :/

Comment: You haven't really made it easy to assist you. We need your data in the question and a really clear designation of what you want after processing. Until you can do that we won't be able to help.

Comment: the data is too long to paste in but would something like this sound like it makes sense for(i in Pollz$Date[1:574]){if (Pollz$Date[i+1>i]){i==i+1}}   if the date below the current date is later then change the current date to that later date also. If i index the date Date[i] if this date is before one that is below it say Date[i+1] then Date[i] becomes Date[i+1]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a prettier way, but this should give the desired output:

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(rev(cummax(rev(as.numeric(data$Date)))), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

The idea is that you want a rolling maximum from the bottom up, for example once the `2018-01-02` was reached, the rows above can not have a date that is "smaller" than the `2018-01-02`. This is done by the `cummax` function. It carries the maximum date reached and overwrites earlier/smaller dates. Since you want it to go from the bottom up, you have to reverse your date column via `rev` and then reverse it back after your call of `cummax`. Because `cummax` only works for `numeric` input I transformed your date column to numeric and back to `date` in the end.

Comment: wait it went funny haha

Comment: What is your output? Did you change `date` to the name of your dataframe?

Comment: Ya I got it I had to state the timezone. Thanks so much !